# Xamarin.Forms Activity restarts on its own

Tags: xamarin, android-activity

This question is already asked here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32931/android-application-restarting, but no one has answered this yet.
I have a Xamarin.Forms application, and when the application starts, everything is okay, but sometimes, it restarts on its own after few minutes, this resets the current state of the app and goes to the main page.

My app has two activities: the first one is the MainLauncher and is the SplashScreen activity. The second activity is the one where my FormsApplication starts. 
This is the second activity which restarts on its own on my Android 7.1.2 device in Debug mode (I didn't test in Release mode by the way).
The activity has the attribute LaunchMode.SingleTop attribute because I read in an other thread it would help, but with no luck.

I added breakpoints all over the activity to catch the process the activity is running through when the restart occurs, and it appears that the activity hits:

```
OnResume(), then
OnStop(), then
OnDestroy(), then
OnCreate(), then
OnStart()
```

But there is no reason for my activity to restart, and I hope somebody can help me or give me an hint because I am really stuck by this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the output window and the call stack when it restarts. this kind of sounds like a crash that is automatically restarting the app. your call stack should be able to tell you exactly where your code is coming from and provide insight into why it's shutting down.

Comment: Which version of Xamarin is the app using? If it's old, it's recommended to update first. Also, you can try create a minimal app with the same lifecycle behavior and see if this issue is reproducible to help locate the issue.

Comment: Hi everybody, I find out that the Android device was connected to a NFC scanner device, and we tried to disconnect it by unplugging its USB wire, and the Xamarin.App did not restart anymore, I mention that my Xamarin App does not work with this NFC scanner at all, but I do not understand this NFC scanner makes my App restart.